# solve Depends for install python3-matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, linux, matplotlib

I am trying to install **python3-matplotlib**  by this command:

`sudo apt install  python3-matplotlib`

but terminal return me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-matplotlib : Depends: python3 (< 3.8) but 3.8.2-3 is to be installed
                      Depends: python3-kiwisolver but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to solve it by:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
sudo aptitude install python3-matplotlib
```

but return:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-lyx{a} libjs-jquery-ui{a} python-matplotlib-data{a} python3-cycler{a} python3-dateutil{a} python3-matplotlib{b} python3-pyparsing{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
Need to get 10.1 MB of archives. After unpacking 28.0 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-matplotlib : Depends: python3 (< 3.8) but 3.8.2-3 is installed
                      Depends: python3-kiwisolver but it is not installable
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     python3-matplotlib [Not Installed]
```

***How can solve it?***

PS: this is information of my OS:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
Release:        8.11
Codename:       jessie
```

Comment: Hello. You can try installing older version of python or this: ```sudo aptitude why-not python3-matplotlib``` 
```why-not``` checks dependencies and returns the reasons it is held.

Comment: I installed another version of Python next to 3.8 and set 3.7 as the default, but again it gives the error that you have 3.8 installed. On the other hand, I can not delete 3.8 because my other programs run with it.
And command
`sudo aptitude why-not python3-matplotlib`
the amount of
 `Not currently installed
The candidate version 3.0.2-2 has priority optional
No dependencies require to remove python3-matplotlib
`
Returned. @T0ny1234

Comment: Strange, can you try installing the `python-matplotlib` package or with `pip3 install matplotlib `? And another thing - have you installed these - `build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev`?